# Deleted Files exe Below Specific Size in flash drive

Tags: vbscript

I have the code from Nathan Rice. It works, but the problem is:

I want sDirectoryPath =  "for any flash drive"

```
'Here we set your global variables. These values
'don't change during the runtime of your script.
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
sDirectoryPath =  "j:\"

RecurseFolders sDirectoryPath

Sub RecurseFolders(sFolder)
  'Here we set the oFolder object, note that it's
  'variable scope is within this sub, so you can
  'set it many times and it's value will only be
  'that of the sub that's currently running.
  Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(sFolder)

  'Here we are looping through every file in the
  'directory path.
  For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
    'This just checks for a file size less than 450Kb
    If oFile.Size < 450000 And Right(LCase(oFile.Name),3) = "exe" Then
      oFile.Delete True
    End If
  Next

  'Here we do the recursive bit. We need to loop through
  'each folder in the directory too and call the same
  'sub to ensure we check every folder in the path.
  For Each oFolder In oFolder.SubFolders
    RecurseFolders oFolder.Path
  Next
End Sub

'When calling subs you don't need to set their value
'to a variable name, and you don't use parenthesis.
Msgbox "Small Calls Deletion Completed Successfully"

'Clean up
Set oFSO = Nothing
```

Comment: >>I want sDirectoryPath = "for any flash drive"<< would you mind stating exactly what you want to achieve? And what you´ve tried? If you want to enumerate all flash drives, and iterate the code over all of them, then tell us so. In the question. Please.

Comment: Who is Nathan Rice? The badminton player? Or http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1391322/ ?

Comment: Flash Disk be possible g: h: j: k: l: ............. Every time change so
i went script detected USB drive automatic 

or Use 
if exist g: ( do Object ) deletle blah blah 
if exist i: ( do Object ) deletle blah blah 
if exist h: ( do Object ) deletle blah blah

Comment: no Nathan Rice some one help me to get this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'Here we set your global variables. These values
'don't change during the runtime of your script.
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")

'We select removable drives from WMI
Set oDrives = oWMIService.ExecQuery( _
    "Select * From Win32_LogicalDisk Where DriveType = 2")

'Loop through the available drives here
For Each oDrive in oDrives
    RecurseFolders oDrive.DeviceID & "\"
Next

'Cleanup
Set oDrives = Nothing



Sub RecurseFolders(sFolder)
  'Here we set the oFolder object, note that it's
  'variable scope is within this sub, so you can
  'set it many times and it's value will only be
  'that of the sub that's currently running.
  Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(sFolder)

  'Here we are looping through every file in the
  'directory path.
  For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
    'This just checks for a file size less than 450Kb
    If oFile.Size < 450000 And Right(LCase(oFile.Name),3) = "exe" Then
      oFile.Delete True
    End If
  Next

  'Here we do the recursive bit. We need to loop through
  'each folder in the directory too and call the same
  'sub to ensure we check every folder in the path.
  For Each oFolder In oFolder.SubFolders
    RecurseFolders oFolder.Path
  Next
End Sub

'When calling subs you don't need to set their value
'to a variable name, and you don't use parenthesis.
Msgbox "Small Calls Deletion Completed Successfully"

'Clean up
Set oFSO = Nothing
```